# Magento 2 overwrite submitted_form.html in module-contact [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to customize the content of the emails that get sent to the administrator when a site visitor uses the contact form, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to get Magento to use the new `submitted_form.html`..

I thought I could just do it in the same way that I overwrite html files in the `frontend` folder, that is, create a directory structure that matches the original, and create a new file with the exact same name, then make sure to remove the symlink to the original file from the `pub/static/` folder, so that Magento will create a new symlink to the new file. However that doesn't seem to work, hence why I'm here.

How am I supposed to overwrite this file specifically `vendor/magento/module-contact/view/adminhtml/email/submitted_form.html`?

Comment: `magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\YourTheme\Magento_Contact\view\adminhtml\email\submitted_form.html` I think http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.. This is how I solved it:

Placed the new submitted_form.html in `app/design/adminhtml/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Contact/email/submitted_form.html`

So it turns out it is exactly the same as a `frontend` overwrite, just using the `adminhtml` directory instead.. I was looking at the wrong thing whilst debugging, so I didn't actually notice that adding the file into this location the first time, actually worked.